# How to get youtube playlist thumbnail url flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube

I am displaying a YouTube playlist in my app using youtube_explode_dart and I am able to get the playlist title author and all videos inside the playlist but while fetching the thumbnail URL of the playlist it gives me a 404 error code also the link generated by youtube_explode_dart when I click on that and open It in my browser then in my browser also it gave 404 error.

[I want to fetch this playlist thumbnail URL.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDCLAK5uy_kjNBBWqyQ_Cy14B0P4xrcKgd39CRjXXKk)

Comment: [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) endpoint with [`part=snippet`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#part) provides [`thumbnails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#snippet.thumbnails).

Comment: @BenjaminLoison how to do with using [youtube_explode_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart) ??